# What does "And boy did he smell like it, she thought. Nothing like a welder with no place to bathe" from “Blood and Chocolate” mean?

Tags: blood-and-chocolate

There is an expression in this book:

> And boy did he smell like it, she thought. Nothing like a welder with no place to bathe.

I don't know what this sentence means exactly or what it's supposed to mean grammatically, because English is not my first language. What does it mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not specifically about science fiction. Would be better migrated to English language stack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's some context to this. The lines that precede it indicate that he's been sleeping rough and sofa-surfing.

> “And when you all arrived,” Rudy continued, “Gabriel was one of the first to get a job and put all his money toward getting others settled **while he crashed on people’s floors or in the woods.”**
>
> *And boy did he smell like it*, she thought. *Nothing like a welder with no place to bathe*. “So you’re gonna support Gabriel at the Ordeal and not go for it yourself,” she said.

She's basically saying that a welder (someone who wears heavy fireproof clothing and sweats copiously) who doesn't have the ability to regularly shower or bathe would smell *distinctively* bad. The "it" that she's referring to is him sleeping rough.

Answer (score 6):

The sentence before your quote must have mentioned an odor or profession (welding?).  In this case "boy" is just an interjection to emphasize the sentence.  It could have been "goodness" or "oh my" or "gosh", but those are all somewhat out date.

The second sentence doesn't really have an idiom, but could be said a little more explicitly as: "There is no smell like a welder who hasn't had a chance to bathe."  With welding being hot work where you need heavy, protective clothing, sweating is extensive...and stinky.